# 2nd order Diophantine Equation, when does it have solution(s)?

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have this problem:
A*x^2 + C*y^2 + D*x + E*y + F = 0, (B = 0 => B*x*y)

I need to know under which circumstances the above has solution(s). 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What kind of solution? Complex numbers (always), real numbers (depends on the discriminant), rational numbers (there are theorems that will help you here), etc. In any case, this belongs on MathStackExchange, not MathOverflow.

Comment: I am more interested in N numbers. 
But solutions in Q could help me as well.

Comment: which theorems are you referring to? Is there a good book that could help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an algorithm to solve quadratic Diophantine equations?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142938/is-there-an-algorithm-to-solve-quadratic-diophantine-equations)

Comment: @DK485 A quadratic equation has a solution in $\mathbb Q$ if and only if it has solutions in $\mathbb Q_p$ for all $p$ and in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

See Paul Garrett's [nice notes.](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/students/reu/hasse_minkowski.pdf)