# Given any $(a,m,n)\in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}^2$ with $\gcd(a,m)=1$ is there a quick way to determine if $x^n\equiv a\bmod m$ is solvable?

Tags: nt.number-theory

If $m=p^k$ is a prime power then I know:

$$\exists x\in \mathbb{Z}:x^n\equiv a\bmod p^k\iff a^{\frac{p-1}{\gcd(n,p-1)}}\equiv 1\bmod p^{j}$$
$$\text{ where: }j=\min\left(v_p(n)+1+[p\mid n][p=2],k\right)$$

Thus if I have the prime factorization of $m$ then by the Chinese remainder theorem I can just verify the above congruence holds for every prime power $p^{v_p(m)}$.

However what if I don't know the prime factorization of $m$?

Is there still a simple way to determine if $x^n\equiv a\bmod m$ is solvable?

What about just the special case when $n=2$ i.e. $x^2\equiv a\bmod m$ with $m$ composite?

Comment: I am afraid that  even if we know in advance that our $n=4k+1$ is a product of two primes, and $a=-1$, there is no quick way to answer, i.e., to determine whether the primes are congruent to 1 or 3 modulo 4.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why? e.g. would it imply we could factor out $n$?

Comment: I do not see how this info yields factorisation, but it looks similar. If we would know prime divisors of $m$ modulo respectively small primes, we could apply Chinese theorem. We know bit less: only the values of Legendre symbol.

Comment: So if $m=pq\equiv 1\bmod 4$ and we know $x^2\equiv -1\bmod pq$ is solvable. Then $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{q}\right)=1$, which means that $p\equiv q\equiv 1\bmod 4$. Though how is this significant enough to disallow the possibility a simple method exists? We already knew that either $p\equiv q\equiv 1\bmod 4$ or $p\equiv q\equiv 3\bmod 4$ since $m\equiv 1\bmod 4$. I mean I do suspect you are right as obtaining this much information about the prime factorization of $m$ seems non trivial, but I want to be sure.

Comment: See my answer at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142938/is-there-an-algorithm-to-solve-quadratic-diophantine-equations

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah okay, so then the answer would be "no" there isn't a simple algorithm because it's at least NP-hard. Should I delete my question then? Or do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: There's a very simple algorithm – just try $x=0,1,2,\dots$ until you find a solution or reach $m$ without finding one. But you really want a *fast* algorithm, and, unless P = NP, it seems that there isn't one. I'm not sure any purpose is served by having the same answer posted at two questions, neither am I sure there's any need to delete your question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Alright, thanks for the help.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residuosity_problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Goldwasser-Micali probabilistic cryptosystem is based on exactly this principle. Let $N=pq$ and let $a$ be an integer with $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{a}{q}\right)=-1$, i.e., $a$ is a non-residue mod $p$ and mod $q$. The numbers $N$ and $a$ are public knowledge. In order to encrypt a single bit $\beta$, choose a random number $r$ and send $c=r^2\bmod{N}$ if $\beta=0$ and $c=ar^2\bmod{N}$ if $\beta=1$. It seems to be a hard problem to determine $\beta$ unless you know how to factor $N$, but if you do know $p$ or $q$, then it's easy, just compute $\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)$. According to Wikipedia, G-M is "the first probabilistic public-key encryption scheme which is provably secure under standard cryptographic assumptions." See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldwasser%E2%80%93Micali_cryptosystem for further details.