# Polynomial parametrization for solutions of quadratic Diophantine equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

[A previous Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142938/is-there-an-algorithm-to-solve-quadratic-diophantine-equations) asks if there is an algorithm that would determine all integer solutions to a given quadratic Diophantine equation.

To make this question more formal, we need to agree in what form we accept the answer. One standard approach is polynomial parametrization. A subset $S \subset {\mathbb Z}^n$ is a polynomial family if there exists polynomials $P_1,\dots,P_n$ in some variables $u_1,\dots,u_k$ and integer coefficients such that $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in S$ if and only if there exists integers $u_1,\dots,u_k$ such that $x_i=P_i(u_1,\dots,u_k)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. For some equations the solution set is not a polynomial family but is a finite union of polynomial families. The simplest example is the equation $xy=0$ with solutions $(x,y)=(u,0)$ and $(0,u)$.

For some equations like $x^2-2y^2=1$, the solution set is not a finite union of polynomial families.

So, the general question is: **is there an algorithm that, given a quadratic Diophantine equation,  would determine whether its solution set is a finite union of polynomial families, and if yes, produce this parametrization?**

In 2010, Vaserstein https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v171-n2-p07-s.pdf answered a long-standing open question and showed that the solution set to the equation
$$
xy - zt = 1
$$
is a polynomial family.

In the same paper Vaserstein claimed that, much more generally, for any  isotropic quadratic form $Q$ and every integer $c$, the set of integer solutions to
$$
Q(x_1,\dots,x_n) = c
$$
is a finite union of polynomial families. Recall that a quadratic form $Q$ is called isotropic (over the field of rationals) if there exists a non-zero rational (equivalently, integer) solution to $Q=0$. However, there is no proof in that paper, just comment that "We will show elsewhere that..." So, the question is **how to prove this.**

If you prefer a specific example, consider equation
$$
x^2+y^2+zt=1
$$
Is it's solution set a finite union of polynomial families?

Comment: different answers for $Q=c$   and $Q = 0.$  The (primitive) integer solutions to $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ are $(2uv, u^2 - v^2, u^2 + v^2)$ with $\gcd(u,v)=1$ and $u+v$ odd.   Rational solutions to $x^2 - 2 y^2 = 1$  map to integer solutions, with care primitive, of $x^2 - 2 y^2 = z^2 $  Those are $ (u^2 + 2uv - v^2, u^2 + v^2, -u^2 + 2uv + v^2)$ Proof that an isotropic homogeneous ternary has all (primitive) solutions parametrized in this way is proved in Mordell, Diophantine Equations. I imagine we can come up with something for $x^2 + y^2 +zt = w^2 $

Comment: When you mentioned such equations. I think it is necessary to say about the funny result. It may not be immediately detected, but I was surprised when I found a solution. For curves of triangular numbers - when we are looking for parametrization of solutions. There are always solutions. For any equations. I think it's worth mentioning.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794510/curves-triangular-numbers